# Cassandra TLP-Stress Tarball Installation

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-stress

I have just downloaded tarball tlp-stress for cassandra and extracted and found some jars. what the next step to run stress test?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [quick start guide says](http://thelastpickle.com/tlp-stress/#_run_your_first_stress_workload):

> from within tlp-stress run the following command to execute 10,000 queries:
>
> `bin/tlp-stress run KeyValue -n 10000`

you can [specify additional options](http://thelastpickle.com/tlp-stress/#_usage), such as, `--host`, etc., or use different workload (you can get [list of implemented workloads](http://thelastpickle.com/tlp-stress/#_listing_all_workloads) via `bin/tlp-stress list` command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. after extraction there is /lib folder. Inside /lib only jar files. There is no /bin/tlp-stress folder what you are talking about. please help me

Comment: I just downloaded the release version from https://dl.bintray.com/thelastpickle/tlp-tools-tarball/tlp-stress-1.0.0.tar, unpacked and see the `bin` folder in directory. Here is what I did: https://gist.github.com/alexott/8175be069ce5f4c20656c32565b56d1b

Comment: Alex, Again I have downloaded the tar file manually not from curl command. extracted the file and found /lib folder and inside lib only jar files. Request you to download manually and extract the tar. Thanks

Comment: works just fine: ```>tar xvf ~/work/ddac/tlp-stress-1.0.0.tar
x tlp-stress-1.0.0/
...
x tlp-stress-1.0.0/bin/
x tlp-stress-1.0.0/bin/tlp-stress.bat
x tlp-stress-1.0.0/bin/tlp-stress
```

Comment: It seems issue on my specific server cause when I have extracted on other server I can find /bin and /lib both. Thanks Alex.

Comment: One more thing, In the stress run, Can we use different port instead default 9042. I can not see port option. Can you put full command with port, consistency, replication, user/pass etc.